# How to add NSMurableArray to NSMutableDictionary to sort in alphbetical order

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

Actually, I have 2 questions...

1)I have a NSMutableArray that i am displaying it in a table view. I have included a search bar for searching the table view. Now i want to add the array to NSMutableDictionary with alphabets as keys.

2)I want to display this NSDictionary in table view as grouped table with numbers and alphabets as groups. The search results must also yield grouped table view...

Please direct me to a solution. I have been trying to achieve it since long time... Any source or tutorial will be of great help...

Comment: about 2.) What is wrong with the answer i gave u on ur first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068616/how-to-display-xml-data-that-is-stored-as-global-data-in-grouped-table-view ?