# How to display xml data that is stored as Global data in grouped table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am using XML Parser to parse a xml file and store as Global data. I am fetching that data and displaying it as a table. I am using this sample to include search functionality.

I wanted to display the dat as grouped table view with alphabets and the titles...

Like --->> |  A  |

```
        Adam

        Apple...
```

Here is how I am displaying the table earlier without groups:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView : (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"acell"]; 

    if(cell == nil) 
    { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"acell"] autorelease]; 
    }

    if(searching)
    {
        Boat *copyboat = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        cell.textLabel.text = [copyboat boatName];
        NSLog(@"%@", [copyboat boatName]);
    }
    else {
        NSSortDescriptor *alphaDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"boatName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        [[data boats] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:alphaDesc, nil]];   
        Boat *fullboat =[data.boats objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.textLabel.text =[fullboat boatName];
        [alphaDesc release];
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

How do I display the data in table view as sections?

Comment: Unrelated to the grouping requirement but you should sort your data once after getting it instead of in every call to cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not mentioning, how your data looks like, to what kind of data you parse it. I assume that "Global data" means some NSArray that is accessible app-wide.
You should really consider of using CoreData, if you are not doing so.

I adapted Apples sample code [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) so that it is not using the authors name to generate the sections, but its first letter.

add this Category on Book before the implementation of RootViewController:

```
@interface Book (FirstLetter)
- (NSString *)uppercaseFirstLetterOfName;
@end

@implementation Book (FirstLetter)
- (NSString *)uppercaseFirstLetterOfName {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName"];
    
    NSString *aString = [[self valueForKey:@"author"] uppercaseString];     
    NSString *stringToReturn = [aString substringToIndex:1];
    
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName"];
    if ([stringToReturn integerValue] || [stringToReturn isEqualToString:@"0"] ) {
        return @"#";
    }
    return stringToReturn ;
}
@end
```

in RootViewController's `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` getter

change

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"author" cacheName:@"Root"];
```

to

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName" cacheName:@"Root"];
```

**edit in reply to comment**

You could us a NSDirectory, that holds the first letter as key and a NSArray with all related data-objects as object.

- `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` would return `[[theDirectory allKeys] count]`
- `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` returns `[[theDirectory allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]`. Sorting not shown here.
- `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns `[theDirectory objectForKey:[[theDirectory allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]]`
- and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you use `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` to adress the right data.

I didn't test this.

Comment: Thaks for reply...You are right about Global data... I dont mind using core data but the app is almost done using the Global array. So it will be tedious to implement core data again. So can u plz tell me a way out using the Global arrays